# Retrieve Sender name from Email

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to copy selected emails to specific folder with sender name, date and message.

I found code on this site. It is saving the email to the specific folder but sender name is showing as a four digit number (0941).

Example
20191219-**0941**--FW_ Subject of mail

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SaveMessageAsMsg()
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objItem As Object
Dim sPath As String
Dim dtDate As Date
Dim sName As String
Dim enviro As String
**Dim sSenderName As String
Dim sSenderEmailAddress As String**
enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
Set oMail = objItem
sName = oMail.Subject
ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "_"
dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
        vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnn", _
        vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & **sSenderName** & "-" & sName & ".msg"
        sPath = "C:\TEST\JV Approval Backup\"
Debug.Print sPath & sName
oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG
Next
End Sub
Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
sChr As String _
)
sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "@", sChr)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you have variables to hold Sender Name and Sender Email Address, you do not copy values to those variables.  I assume the four-digit number you think is the sender name is the time.

There are three sender properties to choose from:  `.Sender`, `.SenderEmailAddress`, and `.SenderName`.  `.SenderEmailAddress` is always the email address.  `.Sender` is almost always a friendly name such as John Smith but very occasionally it is the same as `.SenderEmailAddress`.  `.SenderName` is usually the same as `.Sender` but it is sometimes it is the same as `.SenderEmailAddress`.

(1)  I suggest you replace:

```
Dim sSenderName As String
Dim sSenderEmailAddress As String
```

by

```
Dim sSender As String
```

(2)  Add whichever one of the following you prefer:

```
sSender = oMail.Sender
sSender = oMail.SenderName
sSender = oMail.SenderEmailAddress
```

(3)  Replace:

```
sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _ vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnn", _ vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & **sSenderName** & "-" & sName & ".msg"
```

by

```
sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd"-hhnn") & "-" & sSender & "-" & sName & ".msg"
```

Try the above and report back if it does not give the result you seek.